# String Literal in the temporary object?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am beginner in C++ and its low-level layer (in comparison with Python and so on). I have read on StackOverflow that string literals go into the Read-Only data section ([String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2589949/17652546)), but currently I am reading a C++ book (by Bjarne Stroustrup) and it is written in there that temporary objects end their life at the end of an expression, so:

```cpp
string var1 = "Hello ";  
string var2 = "World";
string var3 = var1 + var2; // string temp = "Hello World" and assign it to var3
```

After execution, will we have **two** `"Hello World"` or only **one** copy will be left?

Hardware:

```
OS: Windows 11;    
Compiler: MSVC;  
Standard: C++11
```

I understand that possibly it can be implementation-defined, but if it is so, please specify for the x86 platform.

Comment: It boils down to what is a literal. `"Hello World"` is a literal (aka a string directly embedded in the source code), but `var1 + var2` is not.

Comment: There is no "but". Literal strings are not temporary. The "read-only data section" is a platform-specific implementation detail. That temporary objects end their lives in the end of expression is a platform-independent question of language semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are the objects that are referred to specifically with the syntax

```
"Hello "
```

or

```
"World"
```

That is what [*literal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) means, an atomic syntax for a value. It does not refer to string values in general.

String literals are not temporary objects. They are objects stored in an unspecified way (in practice, often in read-only memory, as you indicated) and have *static storage duration*, meaning they exist for the duration of the complete program execution.

---

When you write

```
string var1 = "Hello ";
```

you are creating a `std::string` object, and this object is initialized from the string literal. It is neither itself a string literal, nor does it hold or refer to one. It will simply copy the characters from the literal into some storage it manages itself. The `var1` object (if declared at block scope, ie inside a function) has *automatic storage duration*, meaning that it lives until the end of the scope in which it was declared.

---

The line

```
string var3 = var1 + var2;
```

*used to* (prior to C++17) create a temporary `std::string` object, which was returned by the `+` operator overload of `std::string`. Then `var3` was move-constructed from this temporary. The temporary resulting from `var1 + var2` would then live until the end of the *full expression*, meaning until after the initialization of `var3` was finished.

However, since C++17, there is no temporary involved here anymore. Instead, the `+` operator overload will directly construct the `var3` object. Before C++17, this was also allowed to happen as so-called *return value optimization*.

---

So, in your code, there doesn't exist any `"Hello World"` string literal, but there exists exactly one `string` object that holds the characters `Hello World`, and if you are using a pre-C++17 version, there *may* be additionally one temporary `std::string` object that held the same value, but was destroyed after the initialization of `var3`.